# Word describing someone who wants/needs an authority?

Tags: word-request

As far as I know, "authoritarian" is mostly used to describe the power itself ("an authoritarian ruler", for example). However, are there any similar word to describe someone who wants/need an authority to function properly?

Comment: A submissive? But this is probably not the line of thinking you had been going for....

Comment: You could check a thesaurus for antonyms. I didn't find anything off-hand, but the idea could be expressed like: "Jane needed an *authority figure* in order to focus on her work."

Answer (score 2):

Someone who needs or requires some authority figure in their life can be referred to as a **"follower"** (as compared to a "leader").  This is not necessarily a negative, although it has some negative connotations.

> His whole life he had been a *follower* -- he never sought out a leadership position and always avoided the spotlight.

A more negative way to say this, for a group of people who act as followers, is to call them **"sheep"**.

> You lot are just *sheep*, always nodding your heads and agreeing to whatever your candidate says.  Don't you ever think for yourselves?

A more positive way to express this is **"disciple"**, meaning someone who follows a leader in order to learn from them.

> The popular yoga teacher went everywhere with a group of *disciples* in tow.

There are other words as well, just look up the [synonyms of "follower"](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/follower).

Answer (score 0):

subordinate

dependent

lower

subsidiary

tributary

ancillary

Can you find what you are looking for in these words?

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/subordinate

Answer (score 0):

## Subservient

Subservient suggests one who craves someone to direct them.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subservient):

> 3 : obsequiously submissive : TRUCKLING